# How long had the aliens been present on Earth in "They Live"?

Tags: aliens, alien-invasion, they-live

In [*They Live*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/) we see that all advertising is a form of subliminal messaging to control humans.

Since modern advertising arose in the very early 1900's with the work of [Edward Bernays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bernays), can we conclude that the aliens arrived at around the same time? Is there a canon reference for how long aliens had been on Earth?

[image]
[image]

<sup>Was Edward Bernays an alien!? <sup>*Cue dramatic music*</sup></sup>

Comment: They have come here to chew bubblegum and to assimilate us into their galactic civilization. And they are all out of bubblegum.

Comment: Fortunately, Roddy came here to chew bubble gum and kick ass.  Unfortunately's he's all out of ass.

Comment: I had to upvote this question just for the Edward Bernays reference. Now I'll have to watch the movie again if I can find it.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie the homeless guy mentions, how the "*shit's hitting the fan everywhere*" and jobs are disappearing. The hacker mentions the climate is changing and they are terraforming our planet to suit them.

I'm going to say they haven't been here since the beginning but I would say long enough to set up shop. The true answer or should I say the closest is when the hacker tells of first scientists to discover them.

Comment: I hope this helped.